# Brake on a pre-drilled track fork

Tags: brakes, fork, fixed-gear

I want to put a front brake on a Cinelli Parallax (track/fixed gear bike). It’s got a predrilled fork, but still a cap on it (as far as I know the cap is made of some kind of wax). What’s the cleanest way to remove the cap in your experience? I don’t want to mess up the paint layer around the hole. I read that electric tape and an electric drill will do the job. What’s your take on that? Or should I just try to work the break bolt in?

Comment: Try a hairdryer!

Comment: Don't drill it -- you'll risk wrecking the threads.

Comment: @DanielRHicks what's the alternative then?

Comment: If it really is wax you should be able to poke it out with a piece of wire.  I suspect it's plastic, though.

Comment: Wax would be a strange substance to use.  Might be a translation error, or it might  be a thermoset plastic.   What happens if you poke it with the brake bolt, which by definition won't be as wide as the threads in the fork.

Comment: It turns out it was aluminium, the opposite of wax. I drilled it slowly starting with a  3mm tip up to a 6mm. And now the brake fits perfectly. Hopefully I didn't do anything wrong to the fork.